# Entity Framework Ordering Navigate Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i have a query like below

```
 return this.Context.Modules
               .Select(p => new
               {
                   Module = p,
                   Page = p.Pages.OrderBy(c => c.AuthOrder)

               }).ToList()
               .Select(a => a.Module)
               .ToList();
```

but i am using EF 4.2 and i try like this and watching by SQL Profiler,EF generate much more sql queries its nested,i want to only one query for this job like this

```
select * from Modules m join Pages p on m.ID = p.Module_ID
order by p.AuthOrder
```

how is that possible?

Comment: Is ToList() operation is nacessary twice?

Comment: yes?how i can order navigations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query like that

```
select * from Modules m join Pages p on m.ID = p.Module_ID
order by p.AuthOrder
```

can be implemented next way:

```
var q = (from c in Context.Modules
            join o in Context.Pages on c.ID equals o.Module_ID
            orderby o.AuthOrder
            select new {c, o}).ToList();
```

Comment: what is the return type this type?my method is List<Module> but it doesnt convert.

Comment: The return type is an anonymous type. What do you want to get, only modules? Than replace "new {c, o}" with "c" in the query above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for [`Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx)  that specifies related object to include in your result (i.e. which tables must be joined in your SQL request):

```
return this.Context.Modules.Include("Pages")
               .Select(p => new
               {
                   Module = p,
                   Page = p.Pages.OrderBy(c => c.AuthOrder)

               }).ToList()
               .Select(a => a.Module)
               .ToList();
```

---

**Edit**:
Are you sure your query makes sense? You're actually only selecting `Module`, so why are you trying to order `Pages` first?

Comment: @tobias But as you finally only select Module and not Pages, why are you ordering Pages?

Comment: beacuse it has a order(sequence) field in table :),actually its a site menu model,a module has many pages,pages must be ordered under tje each module at that menu.